# Generate fit of virial expansion to osmotic pressure data and obtain second virial coefficient

Tags: physical-chemistry

So I have some osmotic pressure data that I would like to obtain the second virial coefficient ($B_{22}$) for, but I am getting increasingly more confused on how the theory works. I know you can rewrite the expansion in the following manner:

$\Pi (T, c) = RT(c + B_{22}c^{2} + B_{23}c^{3} + ...)$

where $\Pi$ is the osmotic pressure, $T$ the temperature in K, $c$ the concentration and $R$ the gas constant. I would like to do (presumably) a least-squares fit but my maths is a little rusty. Can you do this in Mathematica or Python and if so, is there any literature on this that I can reference? Apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Yes, if you know how to use software such as Mathematica or Python to perform a least-squares fit then you can fit a polynomial in c to the data to extract virial expansion coefficients. Unfortunately that is not a chemistry problem, that is a programming problem.